# Installing Ubuntu on and External Hard Drive and boot in a Mac

Tags: boot, mac, external-hdd

I am trying to install Ubuntu on an external drive and I have tried several ways of partitioning the drive and none have them have allowed me to boot up. The one that is featured in one of the questions on this site:

[Install Ubuntu to Boot from Partition on external Hard Drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/288826/install-ubuntu-to-boot-from-partition-on-external-hard-drive?rq=1)

When I install everything seems to be working and there is never an error message. However when I am choosing which drive to boot up from (holding down option while booting) it does not show up as an option.

I am running Macintosh 10.9 (Mavericks) and I have 8GB of RAM. The External HD that I am using is the Seagate Backup Plus Portable Drive:

http://www.seagate.com/external-hard-drives/portable-hard-drives/standard/backup-plus/

Comment: @guntbert Will [that way](http://askubuntu.com/questions/446682/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-portable-external-hard-drive) result automatically in an installation that's bootable on a Mac?

Comment: @EliahKagan good point - I overlooked the Mac factor.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's possible to achieve this without it, but I managed to get my Mac to boot Ubuntu from an external hard disk by installing an Refind (a boot manager).

Hope this helps.